# How to edit a file with environment variables in jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm bit new to jenkins. What I want is to edit config files with environment variables of jenkins. I tried ant scripts, Nant plugin but all ended up with errors. If anyone knows something about this please help. For example lets think we want to replace word "hello" in C:\files\test.txt to  "bye". word "bye" should be taken from a environment variable of jenkins. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best is to utilize [Jenkins EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). With that you can have a build step to manipulate/generate your properties, and then you can add another build step to load these properties into project environment variables.

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785651) for a more detailed example.