# How to set Jenkins environment variable from script

Tags: xcode, jenkins, development-environment, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to setup a script to increment the build number of my Xcode project. I make an API call to get the current build number, then I wanted to increment it and apply that new number as an environment variable so that the Xcode Plugin can use it.

I have the EnvInject plugin installed but I don't know how to get the var from my shell script into a Environment Variable.

```
APP_BUILD_NUMBER=$(curl --request GET 'https://api.domain.com/api/GetBuildNumber')
APP_BUILD_NUMBER=$((APP_BUILD_NUMBER +1))
```

This sets `APP_BUILD_NUMBER` to the value I need, but how do I assign this to a environment variable so I can access it later on in my job?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add a build step to execute shell - in there determine `APP_BUILD_NUMBER` and output to file, e.g.

```
APP_BUILD_NUMBER=$(curl --request GET 'https://api.domain.com/api/GetBuildNumber')
APP_BUILD_NUMBER=$((APP_BUILD_NUMBER +1))
echo APP_BUILD_NUMBER=$APP_BUILD_NUMBER > build.properties
```

then add build step  **Inject environment variables** and set there *Properties File Path* to `$WORKSPACE/build.properties`

after that `$APP_BUILD_NUMBER` is accessible in all build steps after as environment variable; e.g. in **Xcode** build step

Comment: Please note that the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin plugin doesn't support Pipeline syntax.

Answer (score 2):

These are also worth considering

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin.
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin