# Set Jenkins environment variable in Python

Tags: python, ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm building a Jenkins setup to automate the our iOS (Xcode) builds.

The flow right now is as follows:

1. Build is triggered remotely. Passing the app's name, bundle ID, provisioning profile URL (among other data).
2. Jenkins fetches the latest codebase version from git.
3. A Python script is run to edit the app's Info.plist file based on the data provided in the trigger. This Python script also installs the provisioning profile using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398456/can-an-xcode-mobileprovision-file-be-installed-from-the-command-line).
4. Jenkins uses the [Xcode Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin) to build the project.

The Xcode Plugin allows you to specify the provisioning profile UUID to use to build the app. The Python file in step 3 gets this UUID. So now what I need is to save that UUID so it's accessible in a normal text form for the Xcode Plugin to use.

I've used the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to create and set an environment variable, which works and is usable in the Xcode Plugin's. But I cannot set this environment variable from any script (Python or Shell) while the job is running, it can only be hard-set in the job's configuration page.

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Jenkins environment variable from script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785651/how-to-set-jenkins-environment-variable-from-script)

Answer (score 0):

> But I cannot set this environment variable from any script (Python or Shell) while the job is running,

Yes you can.

- Your Python/Shell script needs to write a value, in format `param=value` to a predetermined `path/to/file.props` (with some back-and-forth, this path can be dynamic too).
- Configure the EnvInject to read from that `path/to/file.props`
- So:

  1. Python/Shell runs dynamically and writes to file.
  2. EnvInject reads the file and loads the environment variables, including `$param`
  3. Your `$param` is now available for the rest of the job/scripts